# Join lines together in file that end with '\'

Tags: python

I am really new to python and for some reason this has stumped me for a while so I figured I'd ask for help.

I am working on a python script that would allow me read in my files but then if there is a '\' at the end of the line it would join the line after it.

So if the lines are as follows:

```
: Student 1 
: Student 2 \
Student 3
```

Any line that doesn't have the colon before it and if the previous line has the '\' I want to combine them to look like this:

```
: Student 2 Student 3
```

Here is what I tried:

```
s = ""    
if line.endswith('\\'): 
   s.join(line) ## line being the line read from the file
```

Any help in the righ direction would be great

Comment: `s.join` doesn't do what you think it does. Also consider that the line in the file has a newline character (`'\n'`) so `endswith('\\')` probably won't catch for that reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`s.join` doesn't do what you think it does. Also consider that the line in the file has a newline character (`'\n'`) so `.endswith('\\')` won't catch for that reason.

Something like this (although somewhat different method)

```
output = ''
with open('/path/to/file.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.rstrip().endswith('\\'):
            next_line = next(f)
            line = line.rstrip()[:-1] + next_line
        output += line
```

In the above, we used `line.rstrip()` to get read of any trailing whitespace (the newline character) so that the `.endswith` method would match properly.

If a line ends with `\`, we go ahead and pull the next line out of the file generator using the builtin function `next`.

Finally, we combine the line and next line, taking care to once again remove the whitespace (`.rstrip()`) and the `\` character (`[:-1]` means all chars up to last character) and taking the new line and adding it to the output.

The resulting string prints out like so

```
: Student 1 
: Student 2 Student 3
```

Note about `s.join`... It's probably best explained as *the opposite of `split`*, using `s` as the separator (or joining) character.

```
>>> "foo.bar.baz".split('.')
['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
>>> "|".join(['foo', 'bar', 'baz'])
'foo|bar|baz'
```

Comment: thanks for the explanation. This helped me understand quite a bit.

Comment: This solution doesn't work if you have multiple lines, one after another, that end in \

Comment: @smartse I think I know what you mean, yeah. You could also sanitize `next_line` in the same way before adding it to the first line. Maybe `if next_line.rstrip().endswith('\\'): next_line = next_line.rstrip()[:-1]` Though, I think the point in this question is still addressed in any case. If you have other issues, consider opening your own question for those issues :-)

Comment: Thanks yeah I solved it just like that and I agree that your answer does solve the question asked - just wanted to note that's it's not a generalised solution

Answer (score 0):

If you can read the full file without splitting it into lines, you can use a regex:

```
import re

text = """
: Student 1 
: Student 2 \
Student 3
""".strip()

print(re.sub(r'\\\s*\n[^:]', ' ', text))

: Student 1 
: Student 2 Student 3
```

The regex matches occurrences of `\` followed by new line and something that is not a `:`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `regex` and `join` to avoid loop if you starts with a list of strings.

```
l = ['a\\', 'b','c']
s = '_'.join(l)
lx = re.split(r'(?<!\\)_', s) # use negative lookbehind to only split underscore with no `\` before it
[e.replace('\\_', '') for e in lx] # replace with '', ' ' if you need so.
```

Output:

```
['ab', 'c']
```